# Does dynamic GroupBy work together with dynamic Where in dynamic LINQ?

Tags: .net, linq, dynamic, linq-to-entities, dynamic-linq

I use this [dynamic LINQ library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) together with Linq-to-Entities.
I build query and after that iterate it with `foreach(object e in query){}`

`query=db.Table1.Where("it.FieldA>10").Select("it.FieldB");` works.
`query=db.Table1.Where(e=>e.FieldA>10).GroupBy("it.FieldB", "it").Select("key")` works.
But `query=db.Table1.Where("it.FieldA>10").GroupBy("it.FieldB", "it").Select("key")` causes `EntitySqlException` with message `The query syntax is not valid., near keyword 'FROM', line 2, column 1.` in line with `foreach` statement.

How can I make it work without exception ?

Note that type of `db.Table1.Where(e=>e.FieldA>10)` is `IQueryable<Table1>`, but type of `db.Table1.Where("it.FieldA>10")` is `System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Table1>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, `db.Table1.AsQueryable()` fixed it, so `db.Table1.AsQueryable().Where("it.FieldA>10").GroupBy("it.FieldB", "it").Select("key")`  works without exception.

The problem was that Microsoft Dynamic Linq library extends `IQueryable<Table1>`, so it does not take effect on `ObjectQuery<Table1>` which is the type of `db.Table1`.